# Amplify user movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to 'amplify' the movement of a player in a virtual reality game. What I mean by this is that one meter of movement in reality is equal to 1.5 or even 2 meters in virtual reality. I'm using the OVR asset provided by Oculus; I can't find an implementation of this online but I've attempted the following:

```
camera.UpdatedAnchors += delegate (OVRCameraRig rig)
{
    float multiplier = 10;
    rig.leftEyeAnchor.localPosition *= multiplier;
    rig.rightEyeAnchor.localPosition *= multiplier;
    rig.centerEyeAnchor.localPosition *= multiplier;
};
```

While the local positions of the anchors above are being manipulated (I confirmed by printing the values), there is no change in the user experience, I feel movement as regularly as I did before. Am I updating the correct values?

Comment: That sounds really nauseating to be honest, because now your body's motion isn't in sync with your motion in VR.

Comment: I know it is ugly but can you try this syntax :

rig.leftEyeAnchor.localPosition = new Vector3(rig.leftEyeAnchor.localPosition.x * multiplier,rig.leftEyeAnchor.localPosition.y * multiplier,rig.leftEyeAnchor.localPosition.z * multiplier);

Comment: Also can you tell us where in your script you assign those values, it is possible that the localPosition is overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: @TJWolschon you're right, I'd just like to play with the multiplier value to get even just a bit more space covered in VR without compromising the user's experience

Comment: UpdatedAnchors  is a standard method of the camera? How is it working? because I can't find it in unity documentation.

Comment: @Nerevar I've updated my question to reflect that I'm using the OVR camera rig, not a standard camera

Comment: I found a discussion about it here, https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/58865/how-to-change-centereyeanchor-position-and-rotation
consider posting on this website also, you will have better chances to find an expert on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method I used was to scale the OVRCameraRig object and adjust the camera's position and field of view such that the perceived size of the user in the virtual world remained unchanged.